# Is there an NSOP theory with FFSOP?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

After talking to a couple of people, I have been unable to determine whether this is even known.

Recall that a first-order theory $T$ has the *strict order property* or SOP if there is a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ (with $x$ and $y$ possibly tuples of variables) and a sequence $\{b_i\}_{i<\omega}$ such that $\exists x (\varphi(x,b_i) \wedge \neg \varphi(x,b_j))$ if and only if $i<j$. It can be shown that this is equivalent to defining a partial order (on some product sort) with infinite chains. A theory is NSOP if it has no instance of the strict order property.

A theory has the *fully finitary strong order property* or FFSOP if there is a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ (with $x$ and $y$ tuples of the same length) with a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i<\omega}$ such that $\varphi(a_i,a_j)$ holds for all $i<j$ but also such that
$$ \neg \exists x_0\dots x_{n-1} \bigwedge_{i<n-1} \varphi(x_i,x_{i+1}) \wedge \varphi(x_{n-1},x_0)$$
for every $n \geq 2$.

It's not too hard to show that having a formula with the strict order property entails having a formula with FFSOP. (A strict partial order will always satisfy the condition in the definition of FFSOP, since it cannot have any loops.)

> **Question:** Is there an NSOP theory $T$ with FFSOP?